# Constructing a (smooth) diffeomorphism between non-smooth manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, examples-counterexamples

I've been trying to construct a smooth diffeomorphism between non-smooth manifolds.  Unfortunately I don't think I know enough manifolds well enough to find an example of this.

Mostly I've been looking at potential diffeomorphisms between $(\mathbb{R},A_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R},A_2)$, with $A_1$ and $A_2$ non-smooth atlases for $\mathbb{R}$.  Is it possible to construct this?  Or can it be proven that if two manifolds are smooth-diffeomorphic, then the manifolds themselves must be smooth?

Comment: How do you define a smooth map between manifolds which don't have a smooth structure?

Comment: @manthanomen, well between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, I could just define the map to be the identity function, which is smooth, but then on $\mathbb{R}$ I could define some atlas on it which isn't smooth.  Maybe I'm not understanding things correctly as differential geometry seems to be notorious for having competing definitions for its standard objects.

Comment: I guess maybe I'm confused about diffeomorphisms because it's required that they be smooth, yet what does it mean for this map to be differentiable at all if you're mapping between topological spaces, since you need more than just a topology to define a derivative, does it mean that you compose it with an acceptable chart from each manifold like so: $\phi_2\circ F\circ\phi_1^{-1}$?

Comment: In reponse to your questions in comments below, it is certainly possible that you can have two functions $f,g$ which do NOT satisfy a certain property (such as smoothness), and their composition $f \circ g$ by some wild coincidence DOES satisfy that property. Generally speaking one should not read too much into these coincidences…. having said that, "coincidences" in mathematics can sometimes be significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "(smooth) diffeomorphism" is meaningless unless you're talking about smooth manifolds.  If all you have is a pair of topological manifolds $M$ and $N$, it is not meaningful to say a map $f:M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism.  To say $f$ is a diffeomorphism, you need to be able to say that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are smooth, but you can't define this without a smooth structure on $M$ and $N$.  It's like trying to define a ring-homomorphism between two groups.

Comment: ok so the reason you need a smooth structure is because when you say $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are smooth, what you're really saying is that $\phi_2 \circ f\circ\phi_1^{-1}$ and $\phi_1 \circ f^{-1}\circ\phi_2^{-1}$ are smooth, for appropriate charts?  Because otherwise I don't see how you talk about a differentiable function between topological spaces.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of a smooth map between smooth manifolds.  There is no definition of a smooth map between topological spaces.

Comment: ok great! that really clears things up, thanks!  Although I guess my original question would be that you can compose two non-smooth functions and obtain a smooth function, (for example composing a non-smooth function with it's inverse), could you not cleverly do this for the above compositions?

Answer (score 3):

So to say that a map $f : X \to Y$ is smooth, or is a diffeomorphism, there have to be smooth structures on $X$ and $Y$. That is, smooth structures are required in the definition of a smooth map.

Here are the relevent definitions:

A smooth atlas for a manifold $X$ is as an atlas such that for any two charts $(U_1, \phi_1)$ and $(U_2, \phi_2)$, the transition function $\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1} : \phi_1(U_1 \cap U_2) \to \phi_2(U_1 \cap U_2)$ is has continuous partial derivatives of all orders. A smooth structure on $X$ is just a maximal smooth atlas for $X$.

A smooth manifold is just a manifold with a smooth structure.

We say that a function $f : X \to Y$ between smooth manifolds is smooth if for every $p \in X$, there is a smooth chart $(U, \phi)$ for $X$ with $p \in U$ and a smooth chart $(V, \psi)$ for $Y$ with $f(p) \in V$ such that $F(U) \subseteq V$ and the transition function $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is has continuous partial derivatives of all orders. Of course, by "smooth chart," we mean a chart in the smooth atlas.

Comment: ok this makes sense.  I guess my issue was that you can compose non-smooth functions and get a smooth function (for instance composing a non-smooth function with its inverse), could you not cleverly do something like that for $\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$?

Comment: @Thoth: The maps $\psi$ and $\phi$ aren't just any maps; they have to be the maps in your smooth atlas.  If you don't have a smooth structure, then you don't have a smooth atlas, so you can't even talk about $\psi$ and $\phi$.

Comment: why can't you talk about the charts $\psi$ and $\phi$ if the atlas isn't smooth, couldn't I still find an appropriate $f$ such that $\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth?

Comment: @Thoth: You can talk about them, but then you're not talking about the definition of a smooth map.  By definition, a map $f$ is smooth if for _smooth charts_, $\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is smooth.  If that composition happens to be smooth for some other charts, that is irrelevant.  For instance, if you take $M=N=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual smooth structure and $f:M\to N$ is some horribly non-differentiable homeomorphism, you could take $\psi=1$ and $\phi=f$ and then $\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$ happens to be smooth.  This doesn't mean $f$ is smooth.